# Creating a new Request with a new URL object

Tags: javascript, cloudflare

In the domain we're working in (Cloudflare workers), we need to create a new Request object to later modify the URL/hostname of the request. Creating a new Request object by cloning the original request is no problem at all:

```
let newRequest = new Request(request);
let response = await fetch(newRequest);
```

But as soon as we feed a new URL object into the Request object, we get different behavior:

```
let newRequestUrl = new URL(request.url);
let newRequest = new Request(newRequestUrl, request);
let response = await fetch(newRequest);
```

I wouldn't expect a change of behavior from the above, because we're feeding in the same url. But this does behave differently and results in JS scripts and other references failing to load etc.

We've proven our problems are caused by these lines, because the following works **successfully**:

```
let newRequest = new Request(request.URL , request);
let response = await fetch(newRequest);
```

Why is it that creating a new URL object, causes a change in behaviour?

Comment: What happens if you don't pass request to the constructor when creating newRequest?

Comment: Problem is you'd lose all the headers etc, we want to keep the request exactly the same but just change the URL/hostname.

Comment: How about re-executing the code that created the first `request`?

Comment: Anyway, as a debug step, after creating the original request, log everything that the second constructor will look for (`request.method`, `request.headers`, `request.body`,`request.mode`, etc....).  One of those things won't be as you expect (see the complete list for the "init" parameter here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request)

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work. There is documentation about why it should work here: https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/templates/pages/modify_req_props/
What are the errors it is throwing specifically? Is the URL you are fetching different from the hostname of the original request? Does it work if you don't include the request when constructing the request (e.g. `new Request(newRequestUrl)`)